# Property attribute in an interface

Tags: c#

i have a property attribute that can be defined once per class, and an empty interface called `ISql` which i just use to mark my objects that are allowed to use my custom buillt ORM.

is there a way to force the class that implements `ISql` to have that attribute at least once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, attributes aren't part of the contract of the interface, in terms of what implementations must provide.

For this sort of thing, I usually just add a unit test which uses reflection to find all implementations and validates it that way. It's not as nice as a compile-time check, but it's the best that's available in this case.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of code validation I like to use [Nitriq](http://nitriq.com/). You can write your own rule very easy using Linq.

For personal use you can just call Nitriq to validate the code.

In large projects I used to put a step on continuous integration to run Nitriq console to validate the rules against the code